# Can't install CRON job

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task

When I try installing my Cron job I get the following error:

"crontab.txt":8: premature EOF errors in crontab file, can't install

Answer (score 54, accepted):

At the end of the file, add a new blank line, and reinstall crontab crontab.txt

Comment: yes this simple suggestions work well.